# cakephp save data with relation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two table `product` and `product_images`

this is my `product_image` table

```
id
product_id
image
time_created
```

i want to save product with product_image in single form
this is my `product/add` form

```
    <?= $this->Form->create($product ,['type' => 'file','enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'])?>
...
...
<input type="file" name="ProductImages[][image]" multiple>
...
...
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

and this is my `add` method in `products` controller :

```
 public function add()
    {
        $product = $this->Products->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $this->request->getData(),[
                    'associated' => [
                    'ProductImages',
                ]
            ]);
            if ($this->Products->save($product)) {

                $this->Flash->success(__('The product has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The product could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $productCategories = $this->Products->ProductCategories->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('product', 'productCategories'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['product']);
    }
```

but nothing saves in product_image table

### update

i tried to create custom array for easier testing but it just saves new product and no product image

```
 $product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product,[
                'title'=>"asxdasxc",
                "price"=>555,
                "alt"=>55,
                "productImages"=>[
                    ['image'=>"sssssssss"]
                ]
            ],[
                    'associated' => [
                    'ProductImages',
                ]
            ]);
```

Comment: ```'associated' => [...``` would be  ```'contain' => ... ```

Comment: Whenever you have problems related to associations, please always include the configuration of the associations in question! This is most likely related to incorrect association property usage.

Comment: the configuration is all right because I can get data with the association correctly . Beside it's auto-generated by cakephp bake so I think that part won't have any issues